# How to reverse relation between vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

---

We have $\vec{u}$ , $\vec{v}$ , $\vec{w}$ are three vectors of vector space

We have $\vec{a} , \vec{b} , \vec{c}$ such as:

$$\vec{a} = 2*\vec{u} + \vec{v} + \vec{w} $$
$$\vec{b} = \vec{u} + 2*\vec{v} + \vec{w}$$
$$\vec{c} = \vec{u} + \vec{v} + 2*\vec{w}$$

How can we write $\vec{u} , \vec{v} , \vec{w}$ in terms of $\vec{a} , \vec{b} , \vec{c}$?

Comment: You have a system of linear equations in the components of the unknown vectors. Do you know how to solve a system of linear equations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\vec a+\vec b+\vec c=4\left(\vec u+\vec v+\vec w\right)$ and$$\vec a=\vec u+\vec u+\vec v+\vec w=\vec u+\frac14\left(\vec a+\vec b+\vec c\right).$$Therefore,$$\vec u=\frac34\vec a-\frac14\vec b-\frac14\vec c.$$The other vectors are similar.